# Integrate WordNet Affect with WordNet

Tags: java, wordnet

I'm using wordnet in java using some of the known api's (JAWS, JWNL). I want to use the same kind of API's to search in Wordnet Affect (WNA), but there is no help on the Internet about the use of WNA. Is there a way to integrate the .xml files of WNA with the dictionaries .../dict/ of Wordnet?
Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Ricardo

Comment: Me too...hope you get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to place both RDF versions of both WNA and WordNet in AllegroGraph, link them via the WN Domains Hierarachy and then access them via the Java Sesame API for AllegoGraph.